# Select dropdown value check and show if Not exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I've `<select>` dropdown which populate alphabet letters as value as follow

```
<select name="brand" required="required">
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
        <?php foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $letter;?>"><?php echo $letter;?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Now I want to check which alphabet already exist in database. The easy way is to check with `Ajax`, can check with `change` function and set alert if selected alphabet already exist in database but wana do it with only `PHP`

First fetch already stored `alphabets` from database

```
<?php $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $brandalphabet = $row["brandalphabet"];
    }
?>
```

And having alphabets;

```
$letter = range('A', 'Z');
```

After this i totally lost how to check which alphabet exit and what if no alphabet exist at all, so how to populate `<select>` dropdown only with letters which not exist in database.

**Note:** mysql is only for reference, I'm using mysqli prepare statement and i also like PDO so please spare me from mysql deprecated warnings.

Comment: So you want to populate letters which are not in database?

Comment: yes, that's what i'm trying to figure out how to achieve it

Comment: For me it is not really clear what are you trying to achieve. So after selecting a letter from first `select` which contains ALL the letters (A-Z) you will need to reload the page with submitted option value to check if the letter exists in DB and to use this information in another `select`?

Comment: @lolbas, On page load, i wana check which letters already exist in database so won't show in select dropdown

Comment: @Shehary what does you table `brand` is filled with? Words or alphabet letters? Solution will vary depending on this

Comment: @lolbas, alphabet only, one in each row, like A and next row B and onwrads upto Z, edited and updated the question.

Comment: @Shehary then the solution is pretty easy. Just use `while` loop to print letters that are only in the database

Comment: @Shehary
Check my answer below. Wrote it using PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query and columnName, also, complete the array till Z.

```
        <?php

$alphabetArray = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
try
{
    $s = $conn->query("SELECT * from brand ")
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$arr = array();
?>
<select name="something">
<?php
while($alphabets = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    $arr[] = $alphabets->brandname;
}

foreach($alphabetArray as $alphabet)
{
    if(!in_array($alphabet, $arr))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $alphabet; ?>"><?php echo $alphabet; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: your solution partially worked, it ONLY shows which letter already exist in database, i played around with code but i think this is wrong `<option value="<?php echo $alphabets->brandletter; ?>"><?php echo $alphabets->brandletter; ?></option>` this or that way it will only show which alphabet i already exist in database not those alphabet which don't exist in database, point is show alphabet which don't exist in database.

Comment: @Shehary
Then let's go the other way round. Code updated.

Comment: i just finished reading about `in_array` thanks mate. it worked like charm

Comment: Indeed it's an impressive function :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i get, you have almost pasted a solution in your post.

The solution is a merged code from your post:

```
<select name="brand" required="required">
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row["brandalphabet"].'">'.$row["brandalphabet"].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [browser view](http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~sslawyer/index.php/)!

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db("user");
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM brand');

#ARRAY OF ALL LETTERS
$allLetters = range('A', 'Z');

#ARRAY OF LETTERS IN DB
$lettersinDB = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     $lettersinDB[] = $rows['brandalphabet'];
}
$result = array_diff($allLetters,$lettersinDB);

?>

<select name="something">

<?php

foreach($result as $letter)
{
    if(!in_array($letter, $arr))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $letter; ?>"><?php echo $letter; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort and time, welcome to stackoverflow, about your answer, you just posted bunch of code lines, a good answer must have explanation that what your code is doing, why it is doing and how it resolve the problem not for me but it help future readers down the road.